# how to scrape the url links in a website using python (regex only)

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, txt

Require to only use regex for **scraping** the rating links, and total is 250 rating links then save it to txt file.

website: https://www.imdb.com/

I have tried previously using beautifulsoup4 but then it was required to only use regular expressions to extract, so I am not sure about it. Do I use re.findall to look for all the links?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

count = 0
all_urls = list()

for tdtag in soup.find_all(class_ = "titleColumn"):
    url = tdtag.a['href']
    all_urls.append(url)
    count += 1

data = np.array(all_urls)
print(data)

np.savetxt('urls.txt', data, fmt = '%s', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Comment: please make a standalone question where all the information are accessible, no pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `re.findall`:

Replace:

```
all_urls = list()

for tdtag in soup.find_all(class_ = "titleColumn"):
    url = tdtag.a['href']
    all_urls.append(url)
    count += 1
```

By:

```
import re

text = html.read().decode('utf-8')
all_urls =  list(set(re.findall(r'/title/tt\d+', text)))
count = len(all_urls)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. May I know if I need to change the count? As my output it printed out total of 0 urls, before it was 250 urls.

Comment: The count is 500. After `set` the count is 250. I updated my answer. Use `len(all_urls)` to get the total length.

Comment: ok, thanks but now it come up with an error saying 'text' is not defined.

Comment: I'm sorry. Replace `text` by `html.read()`. It should be right now :)

Comment: now its working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's my clumsy attempt at that:

```py
from re import compile
from requests import get

BASE = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top'
page = get(BASE)

pattern = compile(r'<a href="/title/([a-z0-9]+)/')
URLs = pattern.findall(page.text)

try:
    f = open('urls.txt', 'x', encoding='utf-8')
except FileExistsError as e:
    print(e)
else:
    for i in set(URLs):
        f.write(f'/title/{i}/\n')

    f.close()
```

- `requests.get(URL)` is a response object. So, you need `requests.get(URL).text` for regex to work on it
- https://regex101.com/ is a handy website you can use to build and test regex
- `try`, `except`, `else` can be used to handle errors if an `url.txt` file already exists
- f-strings are super convenient and I highly recommend you to learn and use them